# How do I get the 'reminders' channel in IFTTT to work with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, if-this-then-that, ios

I'm trying to use the reminders app to send a Gmail email through IFTTT.

I looked into the authorization IFTTT has for Gmail and it appears that it does not have the ability to send emails, so I think this might be the problem.

Has anyone troubleshooted this problem before and found a solution?

Comment: What is the "reminders app"? The Gmail channel most certainly has a [send a message](https://ifttt.com/channels/gmail/actions/34-send-an-email) action. What, in particular, are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about the [iOS Reminders](https://ifttt.com/ios_reminders) channel, perhaps this recipe can be modified to your needs: [Email your boss when you add reminders to your "Work" list](https://ifttt.com/recipes/90227-email-your-boss-when-you-add-reminders-to-your-work-list). It uses the "New reminder added to list" trigger.

The Gmail channel *does* have a send email action, so I don't know why you seem to be having trouble. That said, there are a ton of other ways to send messages through IFTTT, including the generic [email](https://ifttt.com/email) channel.